# How to return object of the protocol in the method

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols, nsobject

I would like to return an object of the protocol in the method. Any quicker way to achieve this? Thanks.

```
#import "OverlayView.h"

@protocol ErrorOverlayDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)errorOverlayOKButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender;
@end

@interface ErrorOverlay : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ErrorOverlayDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Comment: Declare instead `- (void)errorOverlay:(ErrorOverlay*)overlay oKButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender;`. Write `@class ErrorOverlay;` above the protocol definition, and call that method when needed with `self` as the `errorOverlay` param?

Comment: DO NOT use the `strong` for your delegate property, use `weak` instead.

Comment: But its accessed multiple times @Itachi thats why i used with strong

Comment: @DicleY What's your accesses? The strong/weak means the object's ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one more parameter to your method, preferably the first argument, like the example below:

```
- (void)errorOverlay:(ErrorOverlay *)overlay OKButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Then pass `self` as the argument.